# UICollectionView not working without storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hello I have created nib of UICollectionViewCell and set the identifier "gridcell".  I am using following code but is throwing  exception. Here is my code:

```
@implementation PhotosView
-(void)configureView:(id)object
{
    event=object;
   [collectionView registerClass:[PhotosCollectionViewCell class]
             forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"gridcell"];

    if (photos.count<1) {

        NSString* url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@getImage/%d.json",kBaseURL,[event.eventId intValue]];
        [self sendHttpPostJsonRequestWith:url jsonData:nil andRequestId:100];

    }
}

-(void)didReceiveData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *)error andRequestId:(int)requestId
{
    if (data) {
        photos=[PhotosParser parseRoot:data];
        [collectionView reloadData];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)aCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotosCollectionViewCell *cell=[aCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"gridcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

@end
```

And the following is error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier gridcell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Comment: In your -configureView: method, use -registerNib: instead of -registerClass:

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your custom cell first in `viewDidLoad`

Like so:

```
    [self.yourCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhotosCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"gridcell"];
```